# Changing text in checkout and emails

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, language

I'm trying to edit the text on my cart/checkout.

Things such as "GRAND TOTAL EXCL. TAX", I would rather have displayed as "Subtotal" etc.

I've tried editing Mage.Tax.csv with the below changes - but it doesn't seem to alter anything.

```
Grand Total (Excl. Tax),Subtotal
Grand Total (Excl.Tax),Subtotal
Grand Total (Incl. Tax),Total
Grand Total (Incl.Tax),Total
Grand Total Excl. Tax,Subtotal
Grand Total Incl. Tax,Subtotal
```

The location of the file was app/locale/en_US

Is there somewhere else to edit this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change them from two template files and these will change them on the checkout page as well as the shopping cart(not sure if it work for emails but it might), but i don't why you repeated Grand Total (Excl. Tax) and (Excl. Tax) twice also i think you might mean Subtotal (Excl. Tax) and (Incl. tax) as opposed to grand total for first four. But anyways i'm sure you will find these files helpful.

For the Subtotal(Excl. Tax) and (Incl. Tax) you can change them from app/design/base/default/template/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml. Below are lines that need to altered:

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Subtotal (Excl. Tax)') ?>
</td>

 <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Subtotal (Incl. Tax)') ?>
    </td>
```

All you have to do is put Subtotal or whatever you want to replace them with in 'Subtotal (Excl. Tax)' and 'Subtotal (Excl Tax)'.

As for the Grand Total, you can change them from app/design/base/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml. The lines needed to be altered are:

```
   <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
            <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Excl. Tax')?></strong>
        </td>   

<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
            <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Incl. Tax')?></strong>
        </td>
```

Again same modification as above. Please keep in mind that altering these codes directly is very bad practice and i don't advise you to do so, i suggest making another theme or perhaps you are already using another theme, copying the these files to the corresponding locations there and editing there. I am not going to go into more details about theming and such as it is outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this on a theme level. If in your theme you create a locale file `locale/en_US/translate.csv` then you should be able to simply add your translations into this file.

```
"Grand Total (Excl. Tax)","Subtotal"
"Grand Total (Excl.Tax)","Subtotal"
"Grand Total (Incl. Tax)","Total"
"Grand Total (Incl.Tax)","Total"
"Grand Total Excl. Tax","Subtotal"
"Grand Total Incl. Tax","Subtotal"
```